# Java Object Names dont make sense when creating a Linked List from scratch

Tags: java

I doesnt quite get why the part with the object names down there works? I invoke the method append(int number) with a parameter in my main method and create a List of Node Objects that store integer values  this way. However, why wont the object names "temp" and "current" be replaced when a call append a second, a third.... time. They are always the same object names and one object name cant refer to multiple objects, I thought. When I call the method elementAt(), I get everytime the response I wanna have, but I dont know exactly why it did work.

Heres my Code for the Class MyList

```
public class MyList 

{
     Node head;
    int count;
    Node temp;
    Node current;

    public MyList(){
        head= new Node(0);

        count = 0;
    }
    public void append(int number){
        temp = new Node(number);
        current = head;
        while(current.getNext() != null){

            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(temp);
        count++;
     
    }

 public int  elementAt(int number){

        if(head != null){

            current = head.getNext();
            for(int i = 0; i < number ; i++){
               if(current.getNext() == null){
                    return 0;
                }
               current = current.getNext();

            }
            return current.item;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Heres the Code for the Class Node

```
public class Node {
    public int item;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int item){
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next){
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Heres the code for my the Main Class

```
public class MainList {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList list = new MyList();
        list.append(10);
        list.append(20);
        list.append(30);
        list.append(40);
        list.append(50);
        list.append(60);
        list.append(40);

        System.out.println(list.elementAt(0));
        
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not object names.  (Java objects don't have names!) They (`temp` and `current`) are variables that will contain *references* to objects.  When you assign a new value to a variable, you change what the variable holds.

Comment: Note that `temp` and `current` _will_ be replaced each time `append()` is called due to ` temp = new Node(number);` and `current = head;` etc. Having those references at instance level instead of them being local variables in the methods doesn't make sense in my opinion but they _are_ getting changed.

Comment: If they(temp and current) getting changed with every call, how is it possible that I have, in this example, 7 different Node objects in which the variable item, stores the value I pass to the method append()?